# Multiple Imputation (Mice) with Likert Scale + requirements for the imputation

Tags: likert, multiple-imputation, mice

My dataset consists of 8 questionnaires with around 100 items. All items are answered on likert scales (i e. 5 points or 8 points).
I got 95 Observations (N=95).
For some items there are missing values (max 7% missing). I would like to use the R package `mice` to impute them.

Can I use `mice` for quasi-categorical items (likert scale)? To be more specific: Can I use the `pmm` method of `mice` (which assumes continuous variables) even though my items are on a likert scale (which is rather categorical)?

Do I need to check any requirements besides data missing at random?

Comment: This is really too broad for a simple answer, there are whole articles about the topic in your Q3 for instance. It would be better to narrow it down and give more detail about what you think the answers might be and why.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I am most interested in Q1

Comment: @mdewey is it now specific enough?

Comment: Why don't you use ordinal logistic models for the items? You can also use random forests, which have good performance. Both of these are appropriate for ordinal variables.